# Golang build error 0x80000034 (2147483700)

Tags: go, apple-m1

command I ran: go build -o main

output:
`/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: combining dwarf failed: unknown load command 0x80000034 (2147483700)`

go version: `go version go1.16.4 darwin/arm64`

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [issue #47269](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47269).

> load command 0x80000034 corresponds to LC_DYLD_CHAINED_FIXUPS. Support for this load command was added in https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/312729, which is part of Go 1.17.

You should upgrade to Go 1.17 or above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @blackgreen, can solve the problem by upgrading to Go 1.17.

However if not wanna upgrade to Go 1.17, can also try to install an AMD version of Go 1.16 and run again. This works for me on my MAC M1.

Answer (score 0):

If you can disable cgo `CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main` it should build with go 1.16

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac M1 chip, and if you wanna go 1.16, can also try to install an amd version of the go 1.16. This has been tested and worked fine on my machine.

Reference: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1637845585-combining-dwarf-failed%3A-unknown-load-command-0x80000034-solution-in-GoLang